# Закрытие потока и освобождение объектов внутри его

Tags: c#, многопоточность

Вызывается остановка сервера и идет закрытие фоновых потоков, но фоновые потоки получают состояние WaitSleepJoin, так как имеют внутри объект. Чтобы закрыть поток, требуется уничтожить все объекты в нем, но я не знаю как правильно это сделать, так как поток является ParameterizedThread.

Как правильно закрыть остановить сервер, чтоб все дочерние потоки уничтожились вместе с помещенными объектами?

```
public class OnlineServer
        {
            public class ClientInfo
            {
                private string _info;
                private string _dnsName;
                private IPAddress _ip;

                public string GetInfo()
                { return _info; }

                public string GetDnsName()
                { return _dnsName; }

                public IPAddress GetIP()
                { return _ip; }

                public ClientInfo(string info, string dnsName, IPAddress ip)
                {
                    _info = info;
                    _dnsName = dnsName;
                    _ip = ip;
                }
            }

            private Thread _thread;
            private ManualResetEvent _allDone = new ManualResetEvent(false);
            private TcpListener _Listener;
            private bool _isListen = false;
            private ConnectionParser _connectionParser;
            public delegate string ConnectionParser(ClientInfo client);
            private DisconnectionParser _disconnectionParser;
            public delegate void DisconnectionParser(ClientInfo client, Exception exc);
            private ServerError _serverError;
            public delegate void ServerError(Exception exc);
            private IPEndPoint _ipEndPoint;

            public OnlineServer(IPAddress IP, int Port, ConnectionParser ConnectionParser, DisconnectionParser DisconnectionParser, ServerError ServerError = null)
            {
                _serverError = ServerError;
                _thread = new Thread(Server);
                _connectionParser = ConnectionParser;
                _disconnectionParser = DisconnectionParser;
                _ipEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(IP, Port);
            }

            public void Stop()
            {
                _isListen = false;
            }

            public void Start()
            {
                _thread = new Thread(Server);
                _thread.Start();
            }

            public ThreadState GetState()
            {
                return _thread.ThreadState;
            }

            ~OnlineServer()
            {
                if (_Listener != null)
                {
                    _Listener.Stop();
                }
            }
            private void Server()
            {
                try
                {
                    _Listener = new TcpListener(_ipEndPoint);
                    _Listener.Start();
                    _isListen = true;
                }
                catch (Exception exc)
                {
                    _serverError?.Invoke(exc);
                    _isListen = false;
                }
                while (_isListen)
                {
                    _allDone.Reset();
                    Thread thread = new Thread(() =>
                    {
                        new Client(_Listener.AcceptTcpClient(), _connectionParser, _disconnectionParser, ref _allDone);
                    } ) { IsBackground = true };
                    thread.Start();
                    _allDone.WaitOne();
                }
                Thread.CurrentThread.Abort();
            }

            private class Client
            {
                private ConnectionParser _connectionParser;
                private DisconnectionParser _disconnectionParser;
                private TcpClient _client;
                private ClientInfo _clientInfo;
                public Client(TcpClient client, ConnectionParser connectionParser, DisconnectionParser disconnectionParser, ref ManualResetEvent allDone)
                {
                    allDone.Set();
                    _client = client;
                    _connectionParser = connectionParser;
                    _disconnectionParser = disconnectionParser;
                    byte[] bytes = new byte[256];
                    try
                    {
                        int i = _client.GetStream().Read(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);

                        string data = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytes, 0, i);

                        _clientInfo = new ClientInfo(data, Dns.GetHostEntry(((IPEndPoint)_client.Client.RemoteEndPoint).Address).HostName, ((IPEndPoint)_client.Client.RemoteEndPoint).Address);

                        data = _connectionParser(_clientInfo);
                        if (data != null)
                        {
                            byte[] Buffer = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(data);
                            _client.GetStream().Write(Buffer, 0, Buffer.Length);
                        }
                        else
                            _client.GetStream().Read(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
                    }
                    catch (Exception exc)
                    {
                        _disconnectionParser(_clientInfo, exc);
                    } 
                    _disconnectionParser(_clientInfo, new Exception("Connection Closed"));
                    client.Close();
                }
            }

public class OnlineClient
        {
            private Thread _thread;
            public delegate void ConnectionParser(string response);
            public delegate void DisconnectionParser(IPEndPoint ipEndPoint, Exception exc);
            private ConnectionParser _connectionParser;
            private DisconnectionParser _disconnectionParser;
            private IPEndPoint _ipEndPoint;
            private string _info;

            public OnlineClient(IPAddress IP, int Port, string info, ConnectionParser ConnectionParser, DisconnectionParser DisconnectionParser)
            {
                _thread = new Thread(Connection);
                _ipEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(IP, Port);
                _connectionParser = ConnectionParser;
                _disconnectionParser = DisconnectionParser;
                _info = info;
            }

            private void Connection()
            {
                try
                {
                    TcpClient client = new TcpClient();
                    client.Connect(_ipEndPoint);
                    NetworkStream stream = client.GetStream();

                    byte[] data = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(_info);
                    stream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);

                    data = new byte[256];

                    int i = stream.Read(data, 0, data.Length);
                    string responseData = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(data, 0, i);

                    _connectionParser(responseData);

                    stream.Close();
                    client.Close();

                    _disconnectionParser(_ipEndPoint, new Exception("Connection Closed"));
                }
                catch (Exception exc)
                {
                    _disconnectionParser(_ipEndPoint, exc);
                    Thread.CurrentThread.Abort();
                }
            }

            public void Connect()
            {
                _thread = new Thread(Connection);
                _thread.Start();
            }

            public void Disconnect()
            {
                _thread.Abort();
            }

            public ThreadState GetState()
            {
                return _thread.ThreadState;
            }

        }
        }
```

Comment: Объекты не имеют к потокам никакого отношения.  Чтобы закрыть поток,  надо просто вернуть управление (return, а не Thread.CurrentThread.Abort();) из метода потока. Это единственное условие закрытия. Не надо делать Abort самому себе.  WaitSleepJoin означает, что поток ждет чего-то. Посмотрите в отладчике его stack trace и узнайте, чего именно.

Comment: _фоновые потоки получают состояние WaitSleepJoin, так как имеют внутри объект_ — объясните, что это значит, если не сложно.

Comment: Если вы опасаетесь, что при закрытии основного потока сервера, дочерние продолжат жить и не дадут процессу умереть- ставьте дочерним признак [IsBackground = true](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.threading.thread.isbackground%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) при создании, тогда они будут автоматом убиваться при завершении основного потока.

Comment: @VladD Прочел на одной из веток msdn, там было похожее поведение приложения, подумал что такая же ситуация, но это относилось к COM объектам.
Первый комментарий оказался решением моей проблемы, только не пойму разницу между вызовом Abort из вне и самому себе.

Comment: @i4el0vek: Abort не нужно вызывать вообще никогда. Поток должен завершить себя сам.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Объекты не имеют к потокам никакого отношения. Чтобы закрыть поток, надо просто вернуть управление (`return`, а не `Thread.CurrentThread.Abort();`) из метода потока. Это единственное условие закрытия. Не надо делать Abort самому себе :)

Делать Abort другим потокам не рекомендуется. Стоит использовать объекты синхронизации и/или просто глобальные свойства-флаги остановки, по которым функции потоков сами будут возвращать управление.

WaitSleepJoin означает, что поток ждет чего-то. Посмотрите в отладчике его stack trace и узнайте, чего именно. В коде из вопроса поток скорее всего ждет получения данных из сети. Красиво прервать синхронное ожидание не получится. Стоит или задать достаточно небольшой `ReadTimeout`, или использовать асинхронные методы чтения, которые позволяют прерывать ожидание в любой момент.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class OnlineServer
{
    public void Stop()
    {
        _isListen = false;
        _thread.Abort();
    }
}
```